# Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec

Tags: python, install, playframework

Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--broker=amqp://guest@queue:5672//": stat --broker=amqp://guest@queue:5672//: no such file or directory: unknown

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and i found answer on google by link
https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/issues/420

You need set version in Dockerfile
https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/issues/420#issuecomment-921762450

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык. 2. [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)